# Cant loginto microsoft Onedrive from other computers other than the one OneDrive is linked to

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive, sharepoint

I have been using Microsoft Office 365 Education suite for a while. Here is the information from the subscriptions page:

[image]

My personal computer has OneDrive (Windows 10) installed and I have been using it for a few months to sync my files to the cloud to backup the data, and only store the most important files which I change regularly on my local computer. It has been working almost flawlessly so far.

**Problem statement:**

On my project computer, I can login to my OneDrive computer fine through a couple of methods:

1. Using Chrome/Internet explorer on my personal computer: Directly going to https://onedrive.live.com/ or Onedrive.com
2. If I got to my Onedrive folder>Rightclick>View Online, I can go to my OneDrive folder.
3. https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ _edu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx. Here  is the sharepoint-id and  is the unique name from my university. The above url is directly copied from the final landing page if I login through onedrive.com

**Cant login when trying to access OneDrive on other computers or when using private browsing**

Since I am on multiple computers, I use onedrive online through my Chrome browser extensively. So I have to log in to onedrive.com using my credentials on multiple computers. However, I have tried this on multiple computers, using multiple different browsers, incognito mode and normal mode now, and it suddenly stopped working starting 2 days back. If I directly try to go to onedrive.com and sign in, it takes me to my University login page and repeatedly redirects me to this page

[image]

Or this page

[image]

Or this one:

[image]

Without letting me access the onedrive website.

## **Question**

Any idea whats going on? Or who I should contact?

I tried finding information about any contact for Microsoft Education support, but I cant find anything at all.

Comment: "...the unique name from my university" You're using a school account - contact the University's help desk! Good job on explaining the issue, but the login process is controlled by your university through a federated domain most likely.

Comment: OneDrive Business uses Sharepoint, OneDrive which is linked to your personal Microsoft Account does not.  The same client can be used to connect to both services.  "f I directly try to go to onedrive.com and sign in, it takes me to my University login page and repeatedly redirects me to this page" - This means you are trying to log into your Office 365 account (i.e. your school account) which is an entirely different service then your personal account.  **The first image is what is suppose to happen, when you attempt to log into a Office 365 account, what exactly is strange about it?**

Comment: @Ramhound the OP is not trying to login to a personal OneDrive account. See under Problem Statement - "I can login to my OneDrive computer fine through a couple of methods..." #3 - `https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ _edu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx` is what the OP sees when logged in successfully...

Comment: ...You don't have access to Microsoft Support. This is done by your IT department at the University through the Office 365 Admin Portal. That is who you should contact.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I am well aware of that fact.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not trying to login to my personal account. I am using my university OneDrive. Thats what is linked to the OneDrive installed on Windows 10 computer.

Comment: **I am aware of what you are doing.**  I am asking you what do you find strange about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7D6R.png) image.  Due to the account being used, OneDrive redirecting you the Office 365 website, is suppose to happen.  If you had a normal Microsoft Account you wouldn't be redirected.

Comment: @Ramhound, The login page itself isn’t the issue. After providing the university email address, the website forwards me to my university authentication page, when I provide my university uniquename and password. (I have checked that I am using a correct university unique name and password, with yet another university website. We have a common unique name and password to loginto multiple websites. )

Comment: After this, it redirects me to the onedrive page https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7D6R.png, and then back to university unique authentication page. This keeps happening over and over again. Also this happens only if I try to login from any other computer other than my Windows10 computer which is linked to my University OneDrive account. On my Window10 personal computer, it takes me directly to my University OneDrive page, where I can download or browse any file as usual.

Comment: I should also mention, that at somepoint, I did create a personal OneDrive account, with my university email address. Before this issue started happened 2-3 days back, everytime I would login, it would ask me whether I would like to login to my personal account (with my university email ID) or the University account (created by IT admin). I would always click the University account, and that would take me to the correct onedrive

Comment: @Ramhound, are you saying there is a separate URL now for OneDrive for business vs OneDrive personal? 

I have way more storage than is allowed on OneDrive personal.. so its impossible that I am using OneDrive personal. Also the OneDrive on Windows 10 shows "OneDrive for Business", so I am pretty sure I am using OneDrive for Business.

Comment: "are you saying there is a separate URL now for OneDrive for business vs OneDrive personal?" - This was always the case.  It just didn't matter until you created a Microsoft Account, which username, was your school email.  "so its impossible that I am using OneDrive personal." - If you go to Outlook.com, and use your school email, you can access your Microsoft Account. The OneDrive client is currently configured for your Business account, however, you could log into both accounts, if you so desire  The behavior of the desktop client built-into Windows 10 isn't relevant.

Comment: Verify you are logged out of your Microsoft Account before you proceed to log into your Office 365 account.  My suggestion, change the username to your Microsoft Account, you likely have complicated matters by having 2 accounts with the same username.

Comment: Yeah.. I thought about deleting my personal account linked to my University email, but I was kindof afraid that I would actually somehow delete my university account, which would lead to unrecoverable loss of data. Which is why I didnt do that. If its possible to change the email address from my university email to a different email address, that would be a great idea to see if that is interfering. I will try this out..

Comment: To your about loggint out of my personal Office 365 account, I have tried with Incognito mode on multiple devices and multiple browsers, the issue always returns. But I will delete my cache and check what happens..

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt solve it. I changed the alias on the personal account linked to my umich account. Now, I cant even login to my OneDrive for business from my personal laptop. :(